# How I can use pictures in my application? angular cli + webpack

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How I can use pictures in my application? 
How this is configured?

**angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16 (with webpack)**

I tried to puts my images inside assets/images/test.png **or** assets/test.png but does not work!

and how I can grab my pictures from my html?

**angular-cli.json**

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": "assets",
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "mobile": false,
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ],
  ......other things..
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have 404? Please avoid "does not work" without providing error log or anything that can help to identify problem